# How to click on add extension button of chrome using apple script

Tags: applescript

I am trying to automate my chrome extension addition to chrome.
I am able to click on add extension from chrome web store using apple script but I am able to click on the Add extension button.

My current code is
tell application "System Events"
tell application process "Google Chrome"
set frontmost to true
--click button 1 of group 1 of sheet1 of window 2
keystroke "´"
tell window 1
tell (group whose title is "Add "Symantec Extension"?")
get properties
tell button 1
perform action "AXPress"
end tell
end tell
end tell
end tell
end tell

I am trying to click on this button [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing under **macOS Catalina** with **Google Chrome** 89.0.4389.90, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* worked for me, from **Script Editor**:

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    click button "Add extension" of ¬
        group 1 of ¬
        sheet 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        process "Google Chrome"
```

---

**Notes:**

I only had one *window* with two *tabs* open in **Google Chrome** with the *sheet* showing when I ran that *code*.

Comment: I tried the above code with macOs Catalina with Google Chrome 89.0.4389.82 and getting error ... click button "Add extension" of group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of process "Google Chrome"
  --> error number -1719 from sheet 1 of window 1 of process "Google Chrome"